# How to handle large URL parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, query-string

In my hotel booking application which consists of multiple stages like **Hotel Search -> Select Hotel -> Select Room -> Payment** and each stage having different page. All the stages expect many inputs from previous stage (around 5-8 in some cases), like session-id, check-in, check-out and so on. I'm using Query Params for in-app navigation because when user refresh the page it shouldn't break.

The problem I'm facing is, too many fields makes the URL ugly and also nginx throws error at some stage because of large URL. I have tried storing this data in service but it doesn't help because when refreshing the page the data is lost & storing in `localStorage`doesn't looks fine. So, what is right or best approach I can take here to avoid this problems?

Comment: Create a session ID on your backend, store / cache the information related to that id, stick that Id in your url. Or just use local storage.

Comment: There's one more point which I missed to mention, all the hotel data are fetched from third-party API. So in that case I have to make all those API calls from backend, right?

Comment: You could just store the session information on your backend, but you may want a proxy api anyway for other reasons

Comment: I have one more query on this, when I navigate to page 2 i.e. Hotel Room select page, few data like hotel-code, session-id need to be passed from page 2, so creating session wont really help I guess, because this data will be generated based on the user selection and as per your approach this data need to be passed to backend and generate session-id and pass it to third page. Please correct me if I'm mistaken here

Comment: the session id is in the url. you can retrieve the information associated with that ID from your backend on any page. this method does require you to send the information up to the API for it to be cached or stored. or again, just use local storage

Comment: but the catch is few information are generated on the go, like hotel-id, city, no of rooms (page1), hotel-code and session-id (page2), room-id & room-type (page 3) ,and  guest-details (page 4) and many more which wont be available during session id generation.

Comment: It doesn’t matter at all. You’re just associating the information with the session id as it’s selected. The session id is just a pointer. It doesn’t contain the information.

Comment: But my actual challenge is passing data between pages or components, which will be still there.

Comment: no it isn't. they just use the session id to retrieve the data if they have to, you would probably use this in conjunction with a stateful service on the client to avoid excessive trips to the server. the session id and server is just to handle the page refresh scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would introduce an entity to your domain called something like `BookingDraft`, where you are building a booking but it is not a fully featured booking yet.

This entity should have its own unique ID, which will go in the URL.  It should also have the user ID on it if you are going to persist this draft entity to a database.

```js
export interface BookingDraft {
  // Unique identifier for this draft, such as a GUID. Can be persisted to a database, API, or to localStorage. This should go in the URL.
  id:string;
  userId:string;
  hotelId?:string;
  roomId?:string;
  checkIn?:Date;
  checkOut?:Date;
  sessionId?:string;
}
```

Then, your routes would have the booking ID in it, followed by a segment for the step.

```
/create-booking/{bookingDraftId}/select-hotel
/create-booking/{bookingDraftId}/select-room
/create-booking/{bookingDraftId}/payment
```

You can add a guard or some sort of validation logic to each segment's route to make sure the draft already has a `hotelId` before the user tries to select a room:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'create-booking/:bookingDraftId',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'select-hotel',
        component: SelectHotelPageComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'select-room',
        component: SelectRoomPageComponent,
        canActivate: [HotelSelectedGuard]
      },
    ]
  }
]

export class HotelSelectedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private bookingDraftService: BookingDraftService, private router: Router) {}

  public canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean|UrlTree> {
    const draftId = next.paramMap.get('bookingDraftId');

    return this.bookingDraftService
      .getDraft(draftId)
      .pipe(map(draft => {
        if(!!draft.hotelId) {
          return true;
        }

        return this.router.createUrlTree(['create-booking',draftId,'select-hotel'], {
          queryParams: {
            message: 'Please select a hotel before selecting a room'
          }
        })
      }))
  }
}
```

Create a `BookingDraftService` to save and retrieve the booking draft(s) to and from `localStorage` or some API.

Comment: This solution looks promising though I still need to store data in `localStorage`, but what I'm confused is, what is purpose of having session id in the URL?

Comment: There's one issue what I just realized, the URL cannot be share anywhere.

Comment: The ID in the URL is to just make the URL the single source of truth for the ID of the draft that the application is displaying/modifying.  You could instead store the ID in localStorage. You could also just store the entire draft as JSON in localStorage. If you do that though, rather than sending and receiving it via a REST API, then it is only available for a user to come back to if the user is using the exact same browser (and if localStorage hasn't been cleared). If you want a user to be able to start a draft on their laptop and then finish it on their phone, use a REST API to persist it.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing same, storing the data in backend, so user can share URL